Request failed with status code 419 -Nextjs and Laravel Sanctum
I have two projects, Laravel 8 and Next.js. Everything works smoothly when I send a GET request, but I encounter an error when I send a POST request. I've attempted various solutions, but the issue persists. Below is the code I'm using.

env
APP_URL=:http://127.0.0.1:8000
FRONTEND_URL = http://localhost:3000
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN='localhost'
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='localhost,127.0.0.1'

cors.php

    'paths' => ['*','sanctum/csrf-cookie',],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL','http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

web.php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::post('data/save','HomeController@save_data') ;

fronend
axios.ts
const customFetch = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' ,
    headers:{
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials:true,
    //withXSRFToken: true,
})

  const csrf =  await customFetch.get('sanctum/csrf-cookie');
  const response = await customFetch.post('data/save', visa_data);

I tried to usewithXSRFToken: true,  in axios file
but same

Add to .env (laravel)
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000/

